# Some C++11 features missing when using Code Blocks 13.12, MinGW 4.8.1 and SFML 2.1

Tags: c++11, mingw, codeblocks, sfml

Turning to Stack Overflow after exhausting all my efforts.
I'm running Code Blocks 13.12 and MinGW 4.8.1 on a Windows 7 OS 64bit system. I spent two days trying to get the compiler to link (statically) to the SFML 2.1 library. I followed both the SFML [tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/start-cb.php) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqjNOd1UYtE) video tutorial- reinstalling both Code Blocks and MinGW twice before it finally linked.
After that I was relieved that SFML was recognized, but I got 50 errors when I tried to build and run that suggested C++11 features weren't.
Added `-std=gnu++11` to compiler options and 13 of those errors went away.
The remaining errors all fall into two categories: **mutex is not a member of std** and **from time t is not a member of chrono::_V2::steady clock**. I'm not even sure what _V2 is.

What am I missing?

```
-------------- Build: Release in PumpTracker2.0 (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -std=gnu++11 -DSFML_STATIC -O2 -std=gnu++11 -IC:\SFML-2.1\include -IC:\SFML-2.1\include -c C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o

In file included from C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:25:0:
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\Account.h:37:1: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
 std::mutex mu;
 ^
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\Account.h:86:22: error: 'to_time_t' is not a member of 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock'
   time_t currentTp = std::chrono::steady_clock::to_time_t(newly);

C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\Account.h:94:48: error: 'from_time_t' is not a member of 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock'
   std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point tNew = std::chrono::steady_clock::from_time_t(currentTp);
                                                ^
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:51:2: error: 'mutex' is not a member of 'std'
  std::mutex mu3;
  ^
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:51:13: error: expected ';' before 'mu3'
  std::mutex mu3;
             ^
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:52:19: error: 'mutex' was not declared in this scope
  std::unique_lock<mutex> locker3(mu3, std::defer_lock);
                   ^
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:52:24: error: template argument 1 is invalid
  std::unique_lock<mutex> locker3(mu3, std::defer_lock);
                        ^
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:52:33: error: invalid type in declaration before '(' token
  std::unique_lock<mutex> locker3(mu3, std::defer_lock);

C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:214:22: error: 'to_time_t' is not a member of 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock'
       pS->tpNewest = std::chrono::steady_clock::to_time_t(NextPump);
                      ^
C:\Users\WITcom\Desktop\C++\PumpTracker2.0\main.cpp:245:51: error: 'from_time_t' is not a member of 'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock'
       std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point TT2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::from_time_t(pS->tpNewest);
                                                   ^
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))
37 error(s), 47 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s))
```

Comment: Please post the actual error messages you are seeing, in their entirety, and it may be possible to suggest causes.

Comment: Thank you for your initial reply, Mike. I've posted some of the errors- the most pertinent for easy perusal.

Comment: Assuming you are building with `-std=c++11`, the `error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type` is possibly due to the header <mutex> not being included in the file(s) with that error. I can't suggest anything about the `to_time_t` and `from_time_t` errors.

Comment: The standard MinGW distribution lags a lot, most have moved on to mingw64, I would suggest the [nuwen distribution](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html)

Comment: Heck of a suggestion, Mgetz. I'm down to 17 errors now- all errors dealing with time_t have gone and that's very encouraging. Still not recognizing <mutex> and friends, however. Perhaps Mike is right and header <mutex> is not being included. I will investigate further. Any other suggestions are more than welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned the original MinGW distribution is not the best one to go with, if you want to go with up-to-date features. Instead there are projects like [Nuwen](http://nuwen.net/mingw.html) (Stephan T. Lavavej's website) as well as [MinGW Builds](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/) that provide [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net) binaries.

The mentioning of SFML is misleading, since the problems have nothing to do with SFML at all. Keep in mind however that you'll have to rebuild SFML if you change the compiler!

As a next step, it would've been important to post a minimal example of the source code that reproduces the errors, because right now, we can only guess what's going wrong, based on the errors.

If you don't use the GNU extensions explicitly, you should use `-std=c++11` instead of `-std=gnu++11` and if you look at the build command, you'll notice that it's included twice, which is not necessary.

And now to some guessing about the errors:

- `Account.h` - Make sure the `<mutex>` header is included.
- `main.cpp` - Make sure the `<mutex>` header is included.
- `main.cpp` - If `std::unique_lock<mutex>` is from your code, then you need to add `std::`, i.e. `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>`.
- `main.cpp` - `time_t` things seem to be resolved, but make sure anyways to include `<chrono>` and `<ctime`> (since `time_t` is defined in `<ctime>`).

Comment: The note about -std=c++11 vs -std=gnu++11 is well taken. I accounted for all the elements in your checklist before I turned to SO. Posted the bit about SFML because linking its library to the MinGW compiler while keeping C++11 features seems to be a common problem, and I wanted to point others in the direction of a solution to at least part of it. I keep reading that Windows offers minimal C++11 support, so perhaps I should switch to Ubuntu?

Comment: I've never heard of any issues in linking SFML and C++11 and believe me, I'd know (3.8k posts on the SFML forum)... You must be reading odd sources, C++11 doesn't have anything to do with Windows itself, it's all about the compiler. Windows doesn't care whether you write your code in Assembly, C98, C++1y or Delphi as long as you can compile it to a Windows executable. [MinGW-w64 4.8.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/) or even 4.9 features all C++11 features that [GCC has implemented](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).